# Psudo-Sanitize parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm enforcing a rather strict layout of the strings in a database, but I don't want to for the programmer to adhere to that. So I'd like to tell the programmer "pass me whatever and I'll put it in the format required by the database."

For update and new commands, the following overloads in the ActiveRecord are all I needed:

```
def user_type=(ut)
  super(ut.to_s.camelize.singularize.to_sym)
end

def action=(ut)
  super(ut.to_s.underscore.singularize.to_sym)
end
def model=(ut)
  super(ut.to_s.underscore.singularize.to_sym)
end
```

These sanitize the values as they are set, so it guarantees the database is always the right format.

What if I want to expand this to everything, such as

```
find_or_create_by(user_type: user_type, action: action, model: model)
```

Because the values aren't set, they avoid my sanitation methods.

Is there a mechanism to handle that other than overriding every single method in the class?

Comment: are you using `ActiveRecord`?

Comment: @Anthony yah, I'll make that more explicit in the post